# Logical ! (NOT) operator Difference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operators

I am trying to compare two strings and executing some expression based on the result.

Below are the two sample expressions that I have written to compare two strings that doesn't match.

1. `String1 !== String2`
2. `!(String1 === String2)`

Which one is recommended from the above two in performance wise?

Comment: Performance, really? IRL, the latency of a single ajax request will dominate execution time of millions of comparisons. So choose one that reads better.

Comment: This is micro optimisation ad absurdum. First of all write the code that best expresses what you're trying to do and that's most understandable. The difference is so minuscule as to be irrelevant.

Comment: Performance wise it doesn't matter, but the first one seem more logical

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I would like to know which one will perform  better and what is the difference in between those two?

Comment: There is no difference, and they will perform the same.

Comment: i would just not bother about the performance and give importance to readability here, which for me is your first snippet.You are not going to compare loads of string aren't you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case of "microoptimization". In short: Don't worry. Take the version that is more readable (personally I would favour 1. over 2.).

The (only slightly) longer answer is: You can't know which is faster - it depends on the implementation of the interpreter.* Furthermore, your best odds would be to win about one instruction per such statement. Not a whole lot. Any code using memory, loading files or data from a web server, or interacting with the DOM will be **a whole lot** slower than this. That's where your optimizations need to start - *if* your application feels too slow.

*) Basically, `!==` is designed to be one operation, while `!(a === b)` by nature is two operations: A comparison followed by a negation. However depending on the interpreter (or even compiler) an expression like this might be optimized.

Comment: Yes I shouldn't be worried but I want to prefer one as standard when am comparing strings again in future..I am picking up a string from dynamic variable from the page (related to DOM) and comparing it to the predefined text string during the page load.

Comment: @codeMad Use `!==`. There, that's your standard.

Comment: @codeMad: That's why I wrote "take the version that is more readable" and for me that's `!==`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context how you want the effective code block should work. There is no such difference between these two since both are Strict. However if you use == or != then its around 10% slower.

Source: http://www.bcherry.net/playground/comparisons

Answer (score 0):

I believe its `String1 !== String2`. Because there is one logical comparison instead of 2.